# Can this series sum be calculated, if -1<x<1 (converge)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n-1}}{4n+1}$

with -1<x<1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know geometric series? What have you tried?

Comment: multiple by $x^2$ and differentiate, you get a geometric series which can be expressed in closed form. Reverse the operations, ie. integrate and divide by $x^2$, to get the desired function.

Comment: Thank you both... next time I'd show my steps!

Answer (score 0):

You should show some work on your problem. It seems that is your first time so i will do you a favor, but please show some efforts next time. We know that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x},$$ if $-1<x<1$. Now $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n-1}}{4n+1}=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}.$$
Take $$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1},$$ since the convergence is uniformly in $(-1,1)$ we can interchange derivative and $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{4n}=\frac{1}{1-x^4},$$ and you can find $f(x)$ inegrating. So the solution is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n-1}}{4n+1}=f(x)/x^2,$$ if $x\not =0$ and $0$ if $x=0$

Comment: Oh I'm sorry... it is my first time asking a question on this platform; next time I will show my steps and works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would need to know the series of **derivatives** converges uniformly... Instead, you can use a theorem that a power series may be differentiated term-by-term inside the radius of convergence.